# What is the scope of the noImplicitAny compiler flag

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript documentation documents the `noImplicitAny` compiler flag to

> Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.

So in the following code:

```
let x;            // x is of implicitly of type `any`, but no error

function foo(y) { // error: parameter 'y' implicitly has an 'any' type. 
    let z;        // z is of implicitly of type `any`, but no error
}
```

Shouldn't `x` and `z` also be flagged as being implicitly typed to `any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually due to a fix made in version 2.1. Prior to that your code would have thrown errors.

From the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference):

> With TypeScript 2.1, instead of just choosing any, TypeScript will
>   infer types based on what you end up assigning later on.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> let x;
>
> // You can still assign anything you want to 'x'.
> x = () => 42;
>
> // After that last assignment, TypeScript 2.1 knows that 'x' has type '() => number'.
> let y = x();
>
> // Thanks to that, it will now tell you that you can't add a number to a function!
> console.log(x + y);
> //          ~~~~~
> // Error! Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '() => number' and 'number'.
>
> // TypeScript still allows you to assign anything you want to 'x'.
> x = "Hello world!";
>
> // But now it also knows that 'x' is a 'string'!
> x.toLowerCase();
> ```

So in your case TypeScript will actually infer types based on what you assign to it:

```
function foo(y) { 
    let z;
    z = "somestring";
    z.toUpperCase(); // z is string now. No error;
    z = 10;
    z.toUpperCase(); // z is number now; Error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, as soon as `x` is assigned a value, it acquires the type of that value—one that is **not** `any`. `x` retains that type until it is assigned a value of a different type, from which point it takes on the type of the new value.